# Why does jQuery throw an error when I request external resources using an Appcache Manifest?

Tags: jquery, cors, html5-appcache

I have an application that uses a .appcache manifest. Everything works as expected, resources get cached:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

CACHE:
css/images/ajax-loader.gif
[...]

NETWORK:
http://docs.google.com/*

SETTINGS:
prefer-online
```

Now, when I request a CSV resource from http://docs.google.com like so:

```
$.get(url, function (data) {
  // do something with the data
}).fail(function () {
  alert("There was an error in loading current data from the server.");
});
```

the request fails even if I'm acutally online (on both Chrome and FF). Everything worked fine before I used the Appcache.

What is the correct way of requesting external resources while having an Appcache manifest?

Comment: I've come to the conclusion that it might in fact have to do with Cross-Origin Resource Sharing as I don't control google docs (It might have worked before because the relevant file was still in my Browser cache). Chrome shows a status code "cancelled", however, in FF my approach works beautifully. Why is that?

Comment: Look at the 'cache' section in this JQuery.ajax() documentation: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/. What happens if you use this instead of 'get()', with 'cache: false'?

Comment: @Holf Thanks for the suggestion, apparently the real problem was somewhere else, see my answer below (Cost me some hours). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I mentioned in my comment, the problem was not (only) jQuery, but also CORS resp. Google Docs' lack of support of it ("Publish to web" means for download, not for requesting the resource from a different URL, i.e. origin. Apparently Google does not want to add a `Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"`.

So what I did instead was follow this helpful guide: https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/11864/how-can-i-retrieve-records-from-a-google-spreadsheet-in-json-format and https://developers.google.com/gdata/samples/spreadsheet_sample (The URL is now not CSV but JSONP, it also changed to `//spreadsheets.google.com/feeds/list/[...]/[...]/public/values?alt=json-in-script` and jQuery automatically adds the `callback=xxx` when called with:

```
$.ajax({
  url : url,
  type : 'GET',
  dataType : 'jsonp',
  success : function (data) {
    for(var i in data.feed.entry) {
      console.log(entry['gsx$' + 'actualColumnHeader'].$t);
    }
  },
  error : function () {
    alert('Failed');
  }
});
```

This is not nice or clean by any means (Atom Feed instead of CSV or JSON just to parse it back? Seriously?), but it works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I've just get it working with [tabletop](https://github.com/jsoma/tabletop). No more CORS issue.. for now.