# google forms ajax not working

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-forms

I have the following code

```
          $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: 'POST',
                dataType: 'xml',
                crossDomain: true,
                url: 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/11wr4WCia1wxccR4LzBbWQv00jKQ4OJLfkrwtE7xu2244/formResponse',
                data: {
                    'entry.1200061771': subscriber_email
                },
                success: function () {
                    $('.subscribe-form-error').hide();
                    $('.subscribe-form')[0].reset();
                    $('.button-subscribe').val('SUBSCRIBED!');
                    mixpanel.track('Register');
                },
                error: function () {
                    $('.subscribe-form')[0].reset();
                    $('.subscribe-form-error').html('There was an error submitted the form. Please try again later.');
                    $('.subscribe-form-error').show();
                }
            });
        } else {
            $('.subscribe-form-error').html('Please input an email address.');
            $('.subscribe-form-error').show();
        }
```

unfortunately, when I use it I get an error:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check about JSONP and CORS , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172801/why-does-jquery-throw-an-error-when-i-request-external-resources-using-an-appcac

Comment: I tried jsonp. it gives me an error: Refused to execute script from 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/11wr4WCia1wxccR4LzBbWQv00jKQ4OJLfkrwtE7xu14…uery214005268161930143833_1449089424497&entry.1200061771=d&_=1449089424498' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

Comment: I don't think that you can send a POST request to a Google Forms URL.  You can create a stand alone apps script, then send a GET or POST request to the Apps Script, and then the Apps Script can work on the Form.