# CORS issue while submitting data to google forms in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax, cors

**While submitting the data :** 
***Error Message*** : XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://docs.google.com/forms/d/xxxxxxxxxxxxx/formResponse. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8090' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 405.

```
    $scope.postDataToGoogle = function(){
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        crossDomain: true,
        url: 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX/formResponse',
        // dataType: "xml",
        data: tempData,
        }).success(function(data,status){
            //alert(data)
            console.log("Success");

        }).error(function(data,status) {
            console.log('Error:' + status);
        });

    }
```

Comment: Hello this issue may be related to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172801/why-does-jquery-throw-an-error-when-i-request-external-resources-using-an-appcac).  It sounds like google docs doesnt support CORS requests, but the OP posted a work around.

Comment: Google does not support.
this link might useful
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172801/why-does-jquery-throw-an-error-when-i-request-external-resources-using-an-appcac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its not about jquery or angular, CORS allows or disallow done by Back-end server.
Google might not support this.(to access https://docs.google.com)

CORS (Cross-Domain Resource Sharing) allows you to more cleanly separate your front-end from your back-end.

CORS is a group of special response headers sent from the server that tell a browser whether or not to allow the request to go through

Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://example.com.

[Why does jQuery throw an error when I request external resources using an Appcache Manifest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18172801/why-does-jquery-throw-an-error-when-i-request-external-resources-using-an-appcac)

Answer (score 1):

I do have tried with angular still not able solve it, but with  jQuery its works for me.

```
$.ajax({
            url: 'https://docs.google.com/forms/d/xxxxxxxxx',
            data: tempData,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "xml",
            statusCode: {
                0: function () {
                    alert('error');

                },
                200: function () {
                    alert('Thank you for your valuable feedback');

                }
            }
        })
```

Comment: can I send data type as json insted of xml.